# É aceito o uso de expletivos?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade

[Em uma de minhas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3647/quando-usar-condicao-ternaria), fiz menção a uma prática sugerida em um livro de boas práticas de programação. O autor do livro *Código Limpo* sugere, como métrica de qualidade de um código, que se conte a quantidade de vezes que a equipe diz `WTF` a cada minuto de revisão do código. Caso alguém esteja curioso, isso pode ser visto na página XXV do original em inglês (uma amostra digital está [disponível na Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)). Ele também faz uso de outros termos igualmente expletivos durante o texto.

Percebo que quando são usados expletivos em sites de língua inglesa, inclusive no Stack Exchange (especialmente no *Stack Overflow* "matriz"), isso é encarado com a naturalidade de um linguajar do dia-a-dia. O próprio criador do *Stack Overflow*, Jeff Atwood, também foi editor de outro site que tem a expressão no próprio nome (*The Daily WTF*).

No entanto, ao fazer uma tradução literal do termo `WTF` (`que porra é essa`), incomodei alguém. Foi sugerida uma edição à resposta, trocando a expressão por `que coisa é essa`.

Surge então a pergunta: devemos evitar o uso de expletivos? Se sim, devemos evitá-los completamente?

Tenho uma opinião própria sobre o assunto (tais termos não me incomodam, enquanto não forem insultos dirigidos a alguém ou usados em discussões inflamadas). Porém, por ser novato neste site específico, e por me ser uma situação nova, recorro ao meta com esta pergunta.

P.S.: gostaria de lembrar que existem termos do jargão técnico de desenvolvimento de software que derivam do uso de expletivos. Um ambiente "caixa de areia" (do inglês *sandbox*), por exemplo, é chamado como tal por se tratar de um subsistema no qual você pode fazer [expletivo] a vontade.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Particularmente **não** vejo problema algum nisso. Somos todos adultos e encontramos isso a todo mundo em todo lugar. Se não é ofensa à alguém, não há problema.

**Mas...**

Tem pessoas que realmente não gostam. E segundo o Gabe, é possível ter menores aqui. Claro que isso é raro e também ser hipocrisia **se** alguém achar que uma pessoa de 14 anos não está exposto a todo tipo de expressão, mas ainda assim não podemos participar de corrupção de menores.

Esses dias tivemos a oportunidade de ver várias pessoas demonstrando em sites que a visão de mundo delas tem que ser a mesma para todo mundo. Vimos como várias pessoas que não precisam de um site para aprender mais sobre desenvolvimento de software em português têm certeza que ninguém mais precisa e acham que qualquer um que tente fazer isso está errado.

Não vou cometer o mesmo erro de dizer que porque você, eu e outras pessoas aceitarem isso numa boa, deva ser feito sem se preocupar com as pessoas que não gostam. Até porque dá para obter o mesmo resultado sem fazer o que incomoda alguns.

Não estou dizendo que está proibido colocar esse tipo de expressão, mas também acho que pode-se evitar sempre que não acrescentar nada ao que se está escrevendo.

Eu tenho até uma alternativa para esse caso.

A tradução de `WTF` não é `que porra é essa`. Dá para perceber claramente que não é. E não estou sugerindo usar `QPÉE` também. Sugiro traduzir como traduzimos textos. Você entende o que se está querendo dizer com aquilo e encontra outra forma de dizer a mesma coisa. E temos algo compreensível, pelo menos no Brasil, que diz a mesma coisa que `WTF`. É `PQP`. Tem exatamente o mesmo efeito, evita incômodos, e mesmo que alguém se incomode, tem-se o argumento que são apenas três letras e qualquer suposição que elas formam uma expressão ruim, está na cabeça de quem está pensando isso.

Mas também posso sugerir algo mais simples: deixa o `WTF`. Não precisamos traduzir tudo e não precisamos explicar tudo.

Comment: Eu concordo. Principalmente sobre a diferença entre palavrão explícito e implícito... Parece besteira, mas faz diferença. Ainda adiciono que na verdade não somos todos adultos, já que o mínimo de idade necessário é 13 anos.

Comment: Concordo com o penúltimo parágrafo. O The Daily WTF passou muito tempo sendo chamado de *Worse Than Failure*, mostrando que a maldade está nos olhos de quem lê. Gostei também do último parágrafo. Para essa expressão, vou seguir essa filosofia. Obrigado :)

Comment: @Gabe bom ver você colocando sua posição, que vou tomar como oficial. Editei para inserir essa informação relevante.

Comment: E quanto a palavrões explícitos, mas não pesados, do tipo `foda`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19460/4471? `WTF` não vejo problema mesmo, até porque, é uma sigla em língua estrangeira.

Answer (score 4):

Eu não me incomodo, desde que não haja ofensa pessoal nem exagero. Mas sei que tem gente que se incomoda. Acho que neste momento vale a pena soltar um ou outro de vez em quando para sentir como a comunidade reage. O caso que você citou é um indício de que talvez o pessoal não goste muito, mas por enquanto é uma ocorrência isolada.