# Existe alguma forma de reportar usuários com nicks impróprios?

Tags: suporte

Acredito que o nick de um utilizador com quem me deparei não deveria ser permitido existir, ou pelo menos não dessa forma que seja tão ofensivo.

- Existe uma forma de reportar (que não seja perguntas ou respostas) o usuário diretamente?

Comment: Eu acredito que já tenha um post sobre reportar usuários, seria legal uma pesquisada (não tenho como fazer isso nesse momento, estou de saída para um compromisso)

Comment: @Bacco eu encontrei depois de uns minutos procurando porém não existe resposta ou coisas afins para o mesmo ... https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2521/usu%C3%A1rio-aparentemente-zoando  o que torna mais dificil a pesquisa , a pergunta é parecida mas ainda acho que é diferente visto que não há nada criado para o mesmo

Comment: Desculpe o comentário *off-topic*, mas, fui só eu que achei coincidentemente engraçado o **Daniel Gentil** *reclamando* do **Arthur Revoltado**?? rsrs... Mas, voltando ao tópico, eu também fiz uma pesquisa e não encontrei post sobre isso, os mais póximos foram: [O que fazer quando acho uma pergunta com palavrões?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6595/), [É aceito o uso de expletivos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/685/) e [Que tipo de informações são permitidas no perfil do usuário?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7300/).

Comment: Eu já reportei algumas outras vezes casos assim e sempre o fiz através do chat mesmo. Casos de avatares impróprios também.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se o utilizador não tiver quaisquer publicações, não há maneira de sinalizar. Para além disso, geralmente, é preferível não trazer o assunto para o Meta quando se trata de um utilizador específico, também — pode, por vezes, fazer com que uma parte da comunidade de repente "vá atrás" do utilizador com votos, etc. Portanto, em casos como este, o melhor é tentar falar com um moderador numa sala de chat privada, para tentar resolver o problema sem chamar demasiada atenção.

Entretanto, alterei o nome do utilizador em questão.